# How to provide widget way in UMBRACO?

Tags: widget, umbraco

Is there any best practices?

Say, I need to develop a flip-flop block with title/icon on front and text on reverse side.

And I want that user can simply insert that block in a grid. With params, I said above.

From here - I see only macros-way (simple). I mean  - develop each block in macros, so umbraco-engine can paste it (macros) to grid "from-a-box". But, I don't believe it, I can not even create a folder from backoffice for macro!

Harder way - dive into custom property editor, many setups, many moves. And I don't sure - can I paste result into grid?

I see, that people talks about some great package that called "ARCHETYPE", but project is closed for now... Should anyone bet on that?

Which way is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using Umbraco Grid and want to create a custom grid edtior. If that is the case, I would recommend you looking into [LeBlender](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/leblender/). It basically enables you to create grid types in the same way you make document types, including templates.